# sudoers security

Tags: ssh, svn, sudo

I've setup a script to do Subversion updates across two servers - the localhost and a remote server - called by a post-commit hook run by the www-data user.

/srv/svn/mysite/hooks/post-commit contains:

```
sudo -u cli /usr/local/bin/svn_deploy
```

/usr/local/bin/svn_deploy is owned by the cli user, and contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

svn update /srv/www/mysite
ssh cli@remotehost 'svn update /srv/www/mysite'
```

To get this to work I've had to add the following to the sudoers file:

```
www-data ALL = (cli) NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/svn_deploy
cli ALL = NOEXEC:NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/svn_deploy
```

Entries for both www-data and cli were necessary to avoid the error:

```
post commit hook failed: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I'm wary of giving any kind of elevated rights to www-data. Is there anything else I should be doing to reduce or eliminate any security risk?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use something like svnsync.

From their [site](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.ref.svnsync.html) :

> svnsync is the Subversion remote repository mirroring tool. Put
>   simply, it allows you to replay the revisions of one repository into
>   another one.

So, what you can do is to put an entry like this in the post-commit hooks section:

/usr/bin/svnsync synchronize svn://X.X.X.X/ --username XXXX --password 'XXXXXX' --non-interactive

This will sync the updates to the remote server and you also won't need to provide any special privilege to any user.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following you. I'm not trying to mirror a repository. I'm updating working copies on multiple servers.

Comment: Oh yes. misunderstood the question. Sorry for that.

Will see If I could think of any solution and then wil update you for the same.

Comment: The mirrored repository can have its own post-commit hook.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't use a unprivileged user (www-data) to perform administrative tasks. svn update seems more the job of root. So, I would not add this extra privilege for www-data. As you use a SSH connection, you could connect with a key authentication and create a force-command to restrict the action performed by root to 'svn update'. The public key to be saved on /root/.ssh/authorized_keys will look like:

```
command='svn update /srv/www/mysite',ssh-rsa dedllrfflr[...]
```

This way, your connection will be restricted to this particular command, and www-data does not get extra rights.

On client side, the command to launch the update is:

```
ssh -i /path/to/private/key root@server whatEverCommandYouMayImagine
```

Only the command contained in the forced-command will be launch if authentication succeeds

You then may deal with the Unix groups/rights of the uploaded files. For apache, it usually turns on:

```
find /srv/www/mysite -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 640
find /srv/www/mysite -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 750
find /srv/www/mysite -print0 | xargs -0 chown root:www-data
```

Comment: Hi Philippe,

I'm happy to consider alternatives, but the restriction here is that the post-commit trigger is run as www-data. Having this user svn update locally is pretty standard, but I need a method of letting www-data update the remote server.

The cli user has been setup solely for admin tasks between servers in the cluster, so ssh uses public/private keys and is restricted to the local subnet.